# capturing data from the drop down menu and radio buttons

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to capture the data I enter from my form. Once I hit the submit button but I'm having difficulties. Below is my simple code. I'm trying to work on a registration page that captures all the info about a person. Some of the data have a drop down menu and radio button. I want to capture and store everything in the database(mysql).

My servlet code:

```
package com.Registration.Controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AddUserSevelet
 */
@WebServlet("/AddUserSevelet")
public class AddUserSevelet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AddUserSevelet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter write = response.getWriter();

        String username = request.getParameter("uname");
        String password = request.getParameter("pass");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");




        AddUser register =new AddUser();

        if (register.adduser(username, password, country)){

            write.println("You Have Been Registered Successfully");

        } else {
            write.print("ERROR WHILE LOADING");
            }
    }

} 

my adduser class

    package com.Registration.Controllers;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class AddUser {
public boolean adduser(String userName,String password,String country){

        boolean isRegistered = false;
        try{
        Connection con = DB_Connection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into user VALUES(default,?,?,?,?)");
        psmt.setString(1, userName);
        psmt.setString(2, password);
        psmt.setString(3, country);


        int success = psmt.executeUpdate();
        if(success > 0){

            isRegistered = true;


        }
        } 
        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return isRegistered;

    }

}
```

My HTML code:

```
<body>
<form action="AddUserSevelet" method="post">
UserName: <input type="text" name="uname"/><br/><hr/>
password: <input type="password" name="pass"/><br/><hr/>
Country: <input type="text" name="country"/><br/><hr/>

 <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" checked>red
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" checked>blue
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="white">white
 <br/><hr/>
 <br/><hr/>

<select name ="cars">
<option value="BMW"> BMW 320i</option>
<option value="BENZ"> Compressor</option>
<option value="Toyota"> Allion</option>
<option value="Audi"> A5</option>
<option value="Jeep"> Cheroki</option>
<option value="Volvo"> Volvo g5</option>


</select>
<input type="submit" value="Register"/><br/><hr/>
</body>
```

My question is how do I capture the data from the drop down menu and the radio button, if I put change my servlet code to:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter write = response.getWriter();

        String username = request.getParameter("uname");
        String password = request.getParameter("pass");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        String cars = request.getParameter("cars");
        String color = request.getParameter("color");



        AddUser register =new AddUser();

        if (register.adduser(username, password, country, cars , color)){

            write.println("You Have Been Registered Successfully");

        } else {
            write.print("ERROR WHILE LOADING");
            }
```

My class code:

```
 Connection con = DB_Connection.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into 'user'(?,?,?,?,?) VALUES(default,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    psmt.setString(1, userName);
    psmt.setString(2, password);
    psmt.setString(3, country);
    psmt.setString(4, cars);
    psmt.setString(5, color);
```

Im getting the error:

> error while loading and in the console its `java.sql.SQLEXCEPTION:No VALUE specified for parameter 6`

Kindly help me with sugestions or solutions on how I can capture data and insert it or edit it using servlets. I'm a newbie just trying to learn. Thank you!